# Pausing and restarting animations

Tags: swift, animation, uikit

I'm working on a test that uses swift UIKit dynamics to animate a ball across the screen. I want to add a button in the top left of the screen, that when pressed, pauses the screen just how it is, then when pressed again, resumes the animation. If anyone has any suggestions on how to go about doing this that would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to set the speed of the layer of a superview that contains all views being animated to 0:

```
self.view.layer.speed = 0
```

Then set it back to 1.0 when you want the animation to continue.

(It isn't obvious that layers have a speed property. It is there because they conform to the CAMediaTiming protocol.)

Comment: When i used this, it reset the object to its original position, then when it resumed, it snapped back to where it would have been if the game hadn't paused at all, it just doesn't show the animation. Any fixes to this?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this. As I recall you also have to manipulate beginTime. I have a couple of sample apps on Github (written in ObjectiveC) that illustrate it. Take a look at this blog post: http://wareto.com/keyframe-view-animations